# Spring.datasource.initialize=false not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on spring boot and batch application. 
Due to batch, the application tries to connect to datasource
with `spring-boot:run`.
I want to stop that and tried `spring.datasource.initialize=false`

Along with this also put `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`

While the second one works fine, it seems the first one is ignored.

Could someone let me know if there is a way to stop db connection on startup?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Also tried spring.batch.initialize.enabled=false

Comment: You cannot. A `DataSource` is created as soon as it is referenced. The `initialize` property will only stop the creation of the tables not the start of `DataSource` itself.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you don't want to prevent database connection during application startup.

Instead, you want to prevent execution of batch scripts.

Correct me, please, if I got it wrong.

To prevent execution of batch scripts set:

```
spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false
```

Comment: I want to srop both. While I able to stop batch initialization, I am not able to stop database initialization. I want the database to called only when it is actually required and not while loading an initial static index page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that spring/spring-boot loads the whole spring-context when it is "booted". This means, that all defined spring-beans are loaded into the spring-context during this boot-phase. In the case of spring-batch, this also means that the datasource bean is loaded and, if not turned off by "spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false", the spring-batch tables are initialized.

Generally, you cannot prevent this from happening as soon as you have added your spring-batch-starter to your maven dependencies.

Moreover, I don't understand why you want to prevent this from happening. It is just initialisation taking place and, provided that everything is configured correctly, this shouldn't be a problem at all.

Nonetheless, if you really want to stop the datasource from beeing initialized, you could try the following approach. However, I don't know if this will work.

Spring-Batch needs a datasource that is registered under the name "dataSource" in the spring-context. If no spring-bean with that name is found,  it creates its own. But if you provide your own implementation/configuration for it, it will use your spring bean.

What you need to do is, to provide a proxy for a datasource that is loaded lazily and then register it under the name "dataSource" in the context:

```
@Configuration
public class MySetUp {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // ... create your "lazy initializing" datasource 
    }
}
```

But - and let me stress that - this nothing that I would recommend and I don't see a good reason, why this should be necessary to do.

Furthermore, you mention that you only want load "initial static index page" (I assume, you are talking about html, right?). However, I don't see a "batch" use case, which should display html-pages. It would probably be better to have two different applications in this case.

Probably you could provide some more information about your use case.

Comment: I am using spring boot controller and calling a generalized batch job that can be independant of POJO. I was almost there but not yet. Started facing issues with initialization of database. I tried to stop that and really messed up. My app was loading any file without POJo reading thr' itemreader and passing to writer to write in db. But there's where everything got messed up. Now my applicationis not able to read the application. properties file though it is in the class path. While with same workspace and configs other apps are using props, anything that was started with batch is not.

Comment: I will share my code in couple of hours. It is working on a separate machine now but may be you could suggest me a better approach. Thank you.